# Google Sheets VLOOKUP MULTIPLE IF

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, vlookup

is this possible to achieve in google sheets?

if A2=“Bangkok” (vlookup (products!B1:F100) OR else if A2=“New York”(vlookup (products!M1:S100)

Comment: Try like `=IF(A2="Bangkok",vlookup(A2,products!B1:F100,1,FALSE),vlookup(A2,products!M1:S100,1,FALSE))`.

Answer (score 1):

sure:

```
=IFERROR(IF(A2="Bangkok",  VLOOKUP(A2, products!B1:F100, 2, 0), 
         IF(A2="New York", VLOOKUP(A2, products!M1:S100, 2, 0))))
```

Comment: Perfect!, Thank you so much 

Answer (score 0):

A more concise version (given that your post indicates that A2 will only ever be either "Bangkok" or "New York"):

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,IF(A2="Bangkok",Products!B:F,Products!M:S),2,0))`

However, I suspect that your real-world problem is more involved than this and yet perhaps easier to address more efficiently.

If you'd like, share a link to your sheet (or a copy of it) and explain in more detail the full end goal, and either I or another contributor here may very well be able to offer a more comprehensive approach.